# How to I Pull to refresh in webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am new learning.

I made a `UIWebView` on `Xcode`.

Refresh Code simulator is working but not working on the phone.
How to ı can run?

Here is code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     NSString *fullURL = @"http://mysite.com.tr/report";
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     webView.delegate = (id)self;
     [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

     UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
     [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
     [webView.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];
}


-(void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {

    // Reload my data

    NSString *fullURL = @"http://mysite.com.tr/report";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [refresh endRefreshing];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Comment: you dont need rewirte code again use just like this [self.webView reload]; [refresh endRefreshing];

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. 
remove

```
 [super viewDidLoad];
```

And in info.plist file add a property.

[image]

**Note:** Allow arbitrary Loads to YES is not recommended though.Hope you'll figure it out by yourself.

Comment: To setting allow arbitrary loads to YES is not good practice..of course apple will reject your app.Instead of that use Exception domain...

Comment: @DSDharma: he is in learning phase. and you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @HamzaKAVAK: check your internet in phone.